# Cannot connect to local mysql database using IP address

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench, database-connection

I setup mysql server and mysql workbench. When I tried to connect using localhost as Hostname it was successful but when I used my IP address I got the following error:

Failed to Connect to MySQL at :3306 with user root
Host 'hostname' is not allowed to connect to this MYSQL server

-- What I tried ---

- Setting up an inbound and outbound rule in the firewall settings but I am seeing the same issue. The rule is just a port rule to allow connection over port 3306

I am not sure what other settings I need to have in place to allow the connection using my IP address

Comment: "I used my IP address" -- You mean 127.0.0.1 (or any of that block)? Or an address in the LAN?

Comment: I am not using localhost IP address. But like IP address from computer like 192.168.0.121